# LoadRunner11.03 performance issue?

Tags: performance, patch, loadrunner

Recently, I received a PC installed LoadRunner 11.03(perhaps patch 3) from my client and watched a web performance with it by long-run test.
In multiple user test, it seems not to work on proper performance because my web's performance monitor couldn't reach any limitation, usage of CPU, network bands, disk usage per minute, usage of Memory. Only waiting threads was little bad, but it was not obvious.
It seems a sequential behavior rather than a parallel access.
(No error occured.)

So I though it was not problem of servers, but the client have some problem having prevent to be acting parallel access for some reasons.

I don't have proper HP passport ID, I can't access the LoadRunner patches' website.

Please notice me if not LoadRunner patches, especially patch 4 or higher , let it show such the above behavior or not.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you question, are you saying when you run a LoadRunner test you are only seeing one thread active during the test?

Comment: Thanks, your comment. Yeah, That's exactly what I want to say. It's likely single thread application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it sounds like you are just running a script in VUGen. If that is the case I am guessing (based on what you wrote, correct me if I'm wrong) you are running a script in the Virtual User Generator and not in the Controller. LoadRunner is actually a suite of multiple applications. The Virtual User Generator is the script development application, a development environment like Eclipse. It is single threaded and running a script there is meant only to test the script individually.

To run a multi-threaded test you need to use the Controller app and develop a test scenario, assign multiple virtual users (the LR term for concurrent threads) to each script you want to run and execute the test from the Controller. You can configure machines to be the Load Generators (another app set up to run as a process or service) and push out the test from the Controller to the Generators.

Comment: We don't have a LoadRunner now. Although we are going to borrow again it in the near future.
In that time, I'll check at your mention and report something.
Thank you so much!